# When a new version of Scala comes out, is it normal to see dependencies break?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I'm just getting started with Scala development and am trying to add the "newman" library to my project so that I can do JSON+REST.

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.stackmob#newman_2.11;1.3.5: not found
```

There are some mentions on some github issues for the project about there not being 2.11 support.  So, as my question states -- is this normal?  I'm coming from a PHP ecosystem where a new version of of the PHP interpreter seldom causes an issue with composer.

Should I be careful about what version of Scala I'm working with?  Is there a way to bypass this limitation and force the install anyway?  Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

Major versions are not binary compatible with each other, therefore Scala 2.11 requires libraries to be compiled with that major version (and so on for 2.10, 2.12). Please note that Scala's version scheme is `epoch.major.minor`.

The specific issue why Newman isn't available for 2.11 yet seems to be tracked here https://github.com/stackmob/newman/issues/109 and here https://github.com/stackmob/newman/pull/116.

> Should I be careful about what version of Scala I'm working with?

It makes sense to research whether libraries/dependencies are available before picking a specific Scala version.

> Is there a way to bypass this limitation and force the install anyway? Is that a good idea?

No and no.

> How does binary compatibility factor in when Scala is running in the JVM?

The range of JVM class file versions supported by backend is largely unrelated to the Scala version. Currently, scalac emits Java 6 bytecode. This means that the full expressivity of Scala is available on JVMs released since 2006 by default. In the future, it is planned to require at least Java 8, to leverage the new possibilities introduced in that version.

While multiple Scala versions have emitted Java 6 bytecode in the past, please note that major versions are not compatible because Scala keeps refining and improving its standard library and its bytecode generator.

Comment: That's so funny.  Arguably, though, there's a distinction between "usual" and "normal".

Comment: Just for clarity, how does binary compatibility factor in when Scala is running in the jvm?